# getting input values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the values out of the input boxes after clicking the Remove button and before removing the row using jQuery.  Right now I'm just trying to get the first box, but haven't had any luck with my selection attempts.

Here is the latest attempt at retrieving the input value having an .editing class.  By the way, this is not all of the code.  The removeIng function is firing like it's supposed to, I'm just not getting back what I need.

```
$('.remove_ing').click(removeIng);

function removeIng(){ //removes the row
    alert($(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('.editing').val());
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Here is the HTML, I have several rows like this (added dynamically)

```
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' name='ingredient' value='' class='editing' /></td>
  <td><input type="text" class='editing_amt' name="amount" size="8" value="100"/></td>
  <td><select name='meas' class='editing_meas'></select></td>
  <td><input type="button" name="remove_ing" class="remove_ing" value="Remove"/></td>

</tr>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know if I'm misunderstanding, but the only elements that have a class of "editing" actually doesn't have a value!

Comment: Rather than `.parent().parent()`, you should probably do something a little more explicit, like [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). That way if you add a wrapper around your `input` later, you won't break your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click','.remove_ing',removeIng);

function removeIng(){ //removes the row
    alert($(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('.editing').val());
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Instead

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

use

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: How about $(this).parents("tr").first() ?

Comment: @SamCcp  `$(this).parents("tr")` will also work . but `$(this).closest('tr')` is faster .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show that part of the code, I add the removeIng function, along with other things, when the row is created.  Here the function seems to be working because after the alert returns 'undefined' or similar, the row is removed

Comment: @user2879070 what you want than ?

Comment: Awww Yeahh, just checked the jquery docs, you are indeed correct good sir. I've used $.parents() since the dawn of time, now i feel ashamed i didn't knew about this little performance gain with $.closest() +1 beer to you @TusharGupta

Comment: Thanks for the help!!$(this).closest('tr').find('.editing').val() worked! (I could have swore I tried that!) Is .find the best way back down?

Comment: @SamCcp Never be ashamed you learned a new thing today .Be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

If your html is static ( it's not dynamic ) you should give the button an id and preferably the tr too. If that's not the case, then an event delegation is the way to go. 
@Tushar gave you an idea about event delegation.

Anyway, here's a little snippet that might help you.

```
var btn = $(".remove_ing");
btn.click( removeIng );
function removeIng(){
    // get the row
    var tr = $(this).parents("tr").first();
    //get the text boxes
    var txt = tr.find("input[type='text']");
    //loop through the texts
    txt.each(function(){
        alert( $(this).val() );
    });
}
```

In both cases ( dynamic or static html ) this function will get all your inputs text.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll definitely check that out!  Thanks.